# How to print the items from 3 different list into one line

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have 3 list of equal length I need to print each of their items onto one line.
And it is from an input in a while loop so I don't know how long the length is I just know they will be equal.

```
list1 = ["Bob","Joe","Fred"]
list2 = [56,13,16]
list3 = ["1-26-5","1-8-9","1-7-6"]
print "Bob" 56 "1-26-5"
print "Joe" 13 "1-8-9"
print "Fred" 13 "1-7-6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the much hated python3 print function is so powerful

```
from __future__ import print_function

for z in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    print(*z, sep=' ')
```